# How do we get request parameters in processor?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have a custom processor and I need to execute some statements based on request parameters (queryString, post body, etc.) before persisting data in database.

In my example I want to get values of given parameters in the request (cf. below).

What is the (best) way to do this following api-platform recommendation ?

```
final class CustomProcessor implements ProcessorInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly ProcessorInterface $persistProcesor,
        private readonly Request $request,
        private readonly RequestStack $request
    ) {
    }

    public function process(mixed $data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = [])
    {
        // $this->request->request->all(); // empty
        // $this->request->getCurrentRequest()->toArray(); // ok there is body data but I'm not sure this way is advised
        // $operation-> // which methods will give parameters ?
        // statements ...
        return $this->persistProcesor->process($data, $operation, $uriVariables, $context);
    }
}
```

Request:

```
POST https://localhost/api/custom_entities?foo=bar

{
    "attribute1": "hello",
    "attribute2": "stackoverflow"
}
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the data sent (URL and payload) and the data you want to retrieve.

Comment: I have updated, but what i want to retrieve is not really important in my case.

Answer (score 0):

`requestStack` should give you access to the the `GET` parameters and the payload:

```php
    public function process(mixed $data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = [])
    {
        $currentRequest = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

        // read the GET parameter
        $foo = $currentRequest->query->get('foo') ?? null;
        // $foo = 'bar'

        // read the JSON payload
        $content = $currentRequest->getContent();

        $payload = json_decode((string) $content, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);

        $attribute1 = $payload['attribute1'] ?? null;
        // $attribute1 = 'hello'
    }
```

Comment: For me this solution is ok, as i have mentionned in my source code, i can already use `$this->request->getCurrentRequest()->toArray()`, but is it really compliant with api-platform practice ? What about `Operation $operation` that contains all metadata ?

Comment: @Lounis I don't know about ProcessorInterface and the best practices, but this code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should get them using the `$context['filters']` variable.

```php
public function process(mixed $data, Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): void
{
    $foo = $context['filters']['foo']; // = 'bar'
}
```

Comment: Actually with version 3.0, `$context` variable only has key `operation`, `resource_class` and `previous_data` and in no way it contains any request parameters neither `filters`.

Comment: @Lounis are you sure about that? I’m using it everyday in v3. Also, I can’t find any infos in the upgrade guide to v3 about suppressing it.

Comment: The goal is to reach request parameters independently of being a filter or not, with the following request `POST https://localhost/api/custom_entities?foo=bar` how do you get parameter `foo` from `$context` ? I tried as you did, and it did not work.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to set the parameters in the openApi context of the `ApiResource`, if you set them it in it, it will be available in the `filters` context. I’ll update my answer.